# Does first come, first served need to be hyphenated?

Tags: hyphenation

Is first come, first served hyphenated (first-come, first-served?
Thank you.

Comment: What did google tell you?

Comment: Google, quoting the Cambridge Dictionary (of Cambridge University Press) does not use hyphens here, nor does the fount of all wisdom - the OED. However Wikipedia (for what that's worth) does hyphenate it - *a first-come, first-served basis*.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how it's used in a sentence:

This is set on a first-come, first-served basis. 
(Hyphens necessary because it's defining "basis")

Or

Reservations are first come, first served. (No hyphens necessary because it appears after the verb "are")

Edit: I am citing the Chicago Manual of Style "Compounds and Hyphenation" Sections 7.82 and 7.90 on "Compounds According to Type." For phrases such as first come, first served, I would only hyphenate if used as an adjectival phrase as I've indicated.

Comment: Welcome to ELU! Do you have any citations to prove your answer? You may find the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) useful.

Comment: Hello, Nadia. Though 'hyphenate compound premodifiers when using them attributively but not when using them predicatively' is a pretty good rule of thumb, it's not infallible. In this case, different variants seem to be in common use. [ODO, for instance](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/first_come,_first_served), gives a counterexample: ‘tickets are available on a first come, first served basis’. Hyphens are being increasingly commonly dropped where doing so is considered not to lead to confusion.

Comment: I am citing the Chicago Manual of Style "Compounds and Hyphenation" Sections 7.82 and 7.90 on "Compounds According to Type." For phrases such as first come, first served, I would only hyphenate if used as an adjectival phrase as I've indicated.

Comment: Hi, Nadia. You should add your citation to your answer; not all users will read the comments.

Comment: But some compounds retain the hyphens when used prenominally. Hyphens are not always considered mandatory when confusion wouldn't arise were they dropped. [The general analysis has been given on ELU before](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/127994/out-of-this-world-experiences-vs-out-of-this-world-experiences/128002#128002); is this one of the exceptions?