# Hyphenation in compounds with abbreviation remarks

Tags: abbreviations, hyphenation, compounds

So far I understood, that hyphenation should aid readability.

Examples [[1](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/51665/63107), [2](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/207273/63107)]:

> North America-based company
>
> A Gaussian mixture model-based approach
>
> We propose spherical Gaussian-based approximations to calculate this analytically.

Although, this never aligned with my understanding of parsing trees, I would still like to apply this rule.

How does it extend to abbreviation remarks?

> Gaussian mixture model (GMM)-based approach
>
> Non-negative matrix factorization (NMF)-inspired method

My own understanding of how to parse the words is as follows, which does not seem to be reflected in how hyphens are used:

```
{
  {
    {
      Gaussian {
        mixture model
      }
    } (GMM)
  }-based
} approach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyphens are used to compose constituents, either words or phrases, to make words.  Consequently, to know whether a hyphen is appropriate, you have to know the categories of constituents, not just what the constituents are.  Below, I've tried to amend your diagram for "Gaussian mixture model (GMM)-based approach" by adding category (parts of speech) information. NP means noun phrase, N is noun (a word), A is adjective or other noun-modifier (a word), Participle (a word).

```
{NP
  {A
    {NP
      A Gaussian {N
        N mixture N model
      }
    } (GMM)
  }-Participle based
} N approach
```

There are two types of word compounds in the example.  A compound adjective (a word) is made by combining a NP (a phrase) and a Participle  (a word), and a compound N (a word) is made by combining two Ns (words).  For the latter type of compound, a hyphen is often optional.

I'm not sure I see a problem with the hyphenation. I'm worried, though, about the structure of "Gaussian mixture model", which must be a phrase, not a single word, because "Gaussian" is an adjective, and noun-noun compounds can't contain adjectives.  But "Gaussian mixture" should be a constituent, because of the interpretation: mixture of Gaussian distributions.

Comment: The first 3 example sentences in your question looked spot on to me. The later versions looked **ugly.** //  I might have written: 'GMM' or Gaussian mixture model-based approach. After defining my abbreviation with quote marks the first time it was used I would later use simply: GMM-based.

Comment: @RossMurray, I guess this comment on my answer is intended to be a comment on the question, instead.

Comment: YES, and I apologise. // I am new enough here that this is the first time I have made that **particular mistake** . // Can that be fixed by the moderators? // I do not know how to gain their attention. I wiped out somebody else's answer the last time I tried. :(  // You have my blessing to ask them.

Comment: @RossMurray, No matter.  These comments have made clear what happened.