# How many hyphens in University of Oxford-based?

Tags: punctuation, hyphenation

If I attach "-based" to a compound noun, should I put a hyphen between every word? As in:

> I worked for a University of Oxford-based company

Or:

> I worked for a University-of-Oxford-based company

Granted, there are probably better ways of phrasing this. I'm just curious what the prescriptive usage on hyphens would be in this situation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of a hyphen with the word "based"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/207273/use-of-a-hyphen-with-the-word-based)

Comment: Because "University of Oxford" is a multiple-word proper name, I don't think that the linked question (which involves the word string "spherical Gaussian based") is entirely on point. I provided the only answer to that question, so I feel emboldened to point out that the most suitable punctuation in the present case (according to U.S. style guides, anyway) would be a single en dash (**not** a hyphen) after the word "Oxford": "I worked for a University of Oxford–based company." If I can find a better match on EL&U to this particular question, I will add a link to it.

Comment: In that specific phrase, you could either rephrase it or use an en dash (instead of a hyphen). I agree that the linked question is not the same. [How do I hyphenate an open-form compound word with another that should be hyphenated?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51665/how-do-i-hyphenate-an-open-form-compound-word-with-another-that-should-be-hyphen?rq=1) is more relevant. I have voted to reopen this so it can be more appropriately closed.