# What's the difference between 'single-hand' and 'single-handed'?

Tags: compounds, comparisons

What's the difference between 'single-hand' and 'single-handed'? And why? Is meaning of 'single-hand' a subset of 'single-handed'?

Comment: *Single-handed* is figurative and hyphenated; *single hand* is literal and not. *Single-handed* is an idiom meaning "by himself; with help from no one else". *Single hand* does not mean that. It's a simple combination of two words which expresses its meaning directly and literally, as in "the kitten was so tiny I could hold in in a *single hand*".

Comment: But I asked 'single-hand' and NOT 'single hand'.

Comment: What I was trying to tell you is there *is no* "single-hand" (with hyphen). There is only "single hand" (no hyphen) and "single-handed" (infrequently, but not never, spelled without the hyphen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called the past participle.

- The closed-down restaurant.
- The red-haired woman.
- A white-tailed deer.
- The saber-toothed tiger.
- A painted door.
- An unpainted door.

For example,

- A *painted bucket* vs *paint bucket*.
- If you love hyphens, then, *painted-bucket* vs *paint-bucket*.

The hyphen is optional. Read [When to use a hyphen to coin a new word and when to omit a hyphen?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100818/when-to-use-a-hyphen-to-coin-a-new-word-and-when-to-omit-a-hyphen/100822#100822).

The *past* participle, because the state of the object is due to a completed action.

There is difference between "red-haired woman" and "red hair woman".

- "red-haired woman" = a woman haired with red hair.
- "red hair woman" could mean a woman selling/throwing/giving/etc red hair, or a "red-haired woman".

Hyphens are for clarity:
Red hair woman = red-hair woman.

- Single hand: He won the game with a single hand. It was a single-hand game.
- I have only a single hand tonight. All other waiters, except she, have gone home for the New Year.
- Single-handed: He single-handedly won the game with a single hand. It was a single-handed single-hand feat.

A hand is one cycle of a card game. A hand, can be used as the term for an employee or hired help.

---

[sin·gle-hand·ed](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/single-handed) also sin·gle·han·ded (sĭng′gəl-hăn′dĭd)

adj.

1. Working or done without help; unassisted.
2. Intended for use with one hand.
3. Having or using only one hand.
4. Nautical Of, being, or restricted to a one-person sailing crew.

adv.

- In a single-handed manner.
- sin′gle-hand′ed·ly adv.

sin′gle-hand′ed·ness n.

*American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. Copyright © 2011 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. Published by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. All rights reserved.*