# When to use a hyphen?

Tags: hyphenation

As a non-native speaker, i wonder whether there are any guidelines concerning the usage of hyphens.

Would you write

> Task-planning for robots ...

or rather

> Task planning for robots ...

Comment: See this link http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp

Comment: Ok! None of these rules suggests the usage of a hyphen for the case above. I hope I did interpret this correctly.

Comment: @FloRyan There is no strict rule on using hyphen in your case. It's up to you. Using it is recommended to prevent any confusion. Not a must.

Comment: @Rathony  Thank you. I will stick with your recommendation then.

Comment: @FloRyan My pleasure. Welcome to EL&U. Hope your English will get better and better.

Comment: @Rathony If you would write your comment as an answer, I could mark this question as answered.

Comment: I  would insert the hyphen, usually, compounds which act like adjectives are joined by a hyphen.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100818/when-to-use-a-hyphen-to-coin-a-new-word-and-when-to-omit-a-hyphen/

Comment: That link has some nice answers.

Answer (score 0):

"Task planning," as you must know, isn't common enough to make into any dictionary yet, so there are no formal guidelines.  So we'll have to go with a short survey of how people use it:

Googling it shows, at least on the first page, no hyphens.

Consider also "robot path planning," a similar term but a more common one.  I've never seen "path planning" hyphenated.

So our best answer based on existing nomenclature is:  don't hyphenate.