# Should I hyphenate "rational expectations" when used as an adjective?

Tags: hyphenation

Should a hyphen be used between "rational" and "expectations" in phrases like "rational expectations equilibrium" or "rational expectations condition" in an academic paper? The practice seems uncommon in economics so I am wondering whether an exception to the usual rule applies here.

Comment: I don't think you should be using "rational expectations" adjectivally in the first place! It's a completely non-standard usage, which in any other context would normally be enclosed in *"**scare quotes**"*. But any usage that would normally be set off with scare quotes definitely shouldn't be used in an academic paper.

Comment: Science Direct seems to buck the trend, slavishly following the rule-of-thumb to hyphenate novel-ish compound modifiers but most institutions think the hyphen is better ditched here as the people using / encountering the strings will know how to read them. This is covered in general at Zou's question you later cite, and these particular examples, in the grey area, can easily be checked for a reasonable estimate of relative frequency of use.

Comment: I can't upvote, but both of the preceding comments are helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In current usage, this is possibly an example of omitting a hyphen because the term ("rational expectations") is very familiar to the audience. See [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/100824/320023). However, I do not know that hyphenated usage was ever common.